# Show that $\frac{1}{z^n}$ has a derivative in every neighborhood of $z_0 = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to show that $\frac{1}{z^n}$ has a derivative in every neighborhood of $z_0 = 0$.

What tools should I use to prove this?

My professor has been fairly inconsistent as of late, jumping around in the book from one subtopic to another without ever really proving much or providing concise ways of thinking based on previous material. Also he is often departing from the textbook entirely to prove things, then making errors so numerous that he can't finish the proof in several class periods. Then comes the homework, and we are left hung out to dry because with no textbooks to refer to, and no complete notes (because he himself cannot seem to prove anything).

What I have been given are basic definitions:

1.) Analytic: A function is analytic on a domain $D$ if it is differentiable at all points in $D$.

2.) Entire: A function is entire if it is analytic for all $z$ in the complex plane.

That's it. He mostly just draws pictures to prove things, but he will never accept a picture as a proof on a homework assignment. I'm truthfully lost.

Comment: Set up the problem more carefully.  What is $n$ in your definition?  Why are you trying to prove $z^{-n}$ has a derivative "in every neighborhood of $z_0 = 0$"?  If $n$ is a positive integer (say $n=1$), the function is discontinuous at zero, so definitely not differentiable there.

Comment: If you want to know why I am trying to prove this, you should ask my professor. It was assigned by him. It's interesting that the question was put on hold, when I very clearly stated my question as "What tools should I use prove this", which was well enough understood by at least one person. That person gave me the answer that provided me with the exact tools I needed. If it's unclear to you five fellows what I was asking, then perhaps reading comprehension is a skill you should work on, despite your mathematical genius. Some of the members of this site never cease to amaze me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic rules of differentiation are working in complex analysis just as well as in real analysis. If $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are complex functions that are differentiable at a point $z_0$ and $g(z_0)\ne 0$ then $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ is differentiable at the point $z_0$ as well and the derivative is $\frac{f'(z_0)g(z_0)-f(z_0)g'(z_0)}{g^2(z_0)}$.

So if you know that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the function $f(z)=z^n$ is differentiable (you can prove that using the binomial theorem in the definition of derivative) then you know that $\frac{1}{z^n}$ is differentiable at any point which is not $0$. So yes, it has a derivative in every deleted neighborhood of the origin.